# SimpleXML: do not expand self-closing tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the problem with self-closing tags in SimpleXML. For example, my xml-file:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<a>hello</a>
<b attr="1"/>
</root>
```

PHP code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<a>hello</a>
<b attr="1"></b>
</root>
```

As you can see, SimpleXML converted self-closing tag `<b attr="1"/>` into `<b attr="1"></b>`. I do not need this. How to prevent this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the way you load the XML to

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path, null, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

This gives...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<a>hello</a>
<b attr="1"/>
</root>
```